# Preparing image data for PCA

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pca

Hi I tried to apply PCA on a folder with many pics inside (.jpg). However, I stuck on converting it to the format that scikit-learn PCA accepts. It seems that PCA takes array data format.  I read articles like [PCA for image data](http://www.xiaoliangbai.com/2016/09/07/applying-pca-analysis-on-images) but it looks quite complicated for me. I just want to convert images to accepted format then use `pca.fit`

Before I used os.walk to change images to gray scales and resize them (as below). I was wondering if I can use it on PCA as well.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from PIL import Image 
import os
import numpy as np

WORK_DIR = 'D:/folder/' #working folder
source = os.path.join(WORK_DIR, 'train')  
target = os.path.join(WORK_DIR, 'gray')  

for root, dirpath, filenames in os.walk(source):
    for file in filenames:
        image_file = Image.open(os.path.join(root, file))
        image_file.draft('L', (256, 128)) 
        image_file.save(os.path.join(target, file))
```

Any other easier methods will be great too.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the image data, it would be a 2D array. You have to flatten it out, `.flatten()` would do that. Now you can use this data for `pca.fit()`.

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from PIL import Image 
import os
import numpy as np

WORK_DIR = 'D:/folder/' #working folder
source = os.path.join(WORK_DIR, 'train')  
target = os.path.join(WORK_DIR, 'gray')  

train_data=[]
for root, dirpath, filenames in os.walk(source):
    for file in filenames:
        image_file = os.path.join(root, file)
        print(image_file)
        train_data.append(np.array(Image.open(image_file,'r')).flatten())

pca=PCA()
pca.fit(train_data)
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems that I need to reshape train_data (a list) to 2D array. the message says `ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.` I'm not quite sure the "single feature" meaning in the message. My data are images. If I want to reshape the list to  (-1, 1), how should I change the code?

Comment: looks like there had been no images read in the loop, can you try my updated solution and see if there is any image filenames being printed in the console?

Comment: I still received the same error from the updated code.